# system permissions for Issue in Accepting a Call from user

Tags: android, permissions, phone-call, user-permissions

I develop app where user can use mobile by using voice commands. It Perform all functions successfully. There is Issue in Accepting a Call from user. Rejecting is working fine. It says you need system permissions for this can any one guide how can i get these Permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Add permission android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED or android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS